# Barplot from a dataframe using a column to set the bar colors

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn, stacked-chart

I have a dataframe such as (this is a subset of the dataframe):

```
    Species     Pathway        Number of Gene Families
0   Glovio      ABC                    0.5
1   Glovio      ABC/Synthase           1.0
2   Glovio      Synthase               0.0
3   Glovio      Wzy                   10.0
4   Glovio      Wzy/ABC                0.0
5   n2          ABC                    2.0
6   n2          ABC/Synthase           0.0
7   n2          Synthase               13.0
8   n2          Wzy                    7.0
9   n2          Wzy/ABC                0.0
10  Glokil      ABC                    2.0
11  Glokil      ABC/Synthase           1.0
12  Glokil      Synthase               0.0
13  Glokil      Wzy                    4.0
14  Glokil      Wzy/ABC                0.0
```

I want to plot a stacked bar plot where each bar corresponds to the species (x-axis). The y-axis would display the Number of Gene Families, colour-coded by the Pathway.

I have tried simple things, such as:

```
df[['Pathway']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

But I get an error stating that:

```
Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a `set_index().unstack()`:

```
(df.set_index(['Species','Pathway'])
   ['Number of Gene Families']
   .unstack('Pathway')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `searborn` you can specify a `hue` variable when using [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), which will determine the color of the bars according to the different levels:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Species', y='NumberofGeneFamilies', hue='Pathway')
```

[image]

Comment: `sns` does not support stacked bars though.

Comment: yep I seem to have missed the "stacked" part @quang

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't though @quang

Comment: `sns.barplot` has `dodge=False/True` option, which combined with `cumsum()` can allow stacked bar, but can be complicated.

Comment: Funnily enough this was explicitly requested in [this feature request](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1485), which got a rather succinct "no" @quang

Comment: It is a real shame that this feature isn't available! I need to make graphs with quite a few columns and would look so much better if I could stack them :(  I'm resisting moving away from seaborn but think this time I have no choice!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it after reshaping the dataframe like:

```
df.groupby(['Species', 'Pathway'])['Number of Gene Families'].sum()\
  .unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Or with a pivot_table same result:

```
df.pivot(index='Species', columns='Pathway', values='Number of Gene Families')\
  .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True )
```